# Structural change test for data which is not time series

Tags: structural-change

I am preoccupied with an issue that can we use Chow, CUSUM or any other structural change test for a variable which does not depend on time? For example, one wants to determine specific point for changing pattern of data that is not periodically observed (e.g. age vs. height or rate: to find a specific age point that there is a change for height variable). If these are not suitable for such data, can you advise me appropriate method?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding cut-offs in cross-section data is what regression tree algorithms do. These typically consider several possible dimensions in which the data could be partitioned. But, of course, you can confine them to just a single partitioning variable.

Also, some of the regression tree algorithms in the literature employ statistical tests for selecting the partitioning variables to split in using structural change tests. Notably our model-based (MOB) recursive partitioning algorithm is based on Andrews' supF test, a generalization of the classic Chow test. See `mob()` in the `partykit` package for R for a practical implementation and `lmtree()` for a convenient user interface for linear regression trees. The underlying theory is described in: Achim Zeileis, Torsten Hothorn, Kurt Hornik (2008). "Model-Based Recursive Partitioning." *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **17**(2), 492-514. [doi:10.1198/106186008X319331](https://doi.org/10.1198/106186008X319331) (a preprint version is freely available from my web page)